# Why Scala doesn't deduce trait type parameters?

Tags: scala, traits, type-inference

```
trait foo[F] {
  def test: F
}

class ah extends foo[(Int,Int) => Int] {
  def test = (i: Int,j: Int) => i+j
}
```

So the question is, why Scala known to be so smart about types cannot just deduce type `(Int,Int) => Int` from the type of `test` asking me instead to specify it? Or It is still possible? Or maybe this is backed by some thoughts that I don't have in mind.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is basically "why does Scala have only local type inference" or equivalently "why does Scala not have non-local type inference". And the answer is: because the designers don't want to.

There are several reasons for this. One reason is that the most reasonable alternative to local type inference is global type inference, but that's impossible in Scala: Scala has separate compilation and modular type checking, so there simply is no point in time where the compiler has a global view of the entire program. In fact, Scala has dynamic code loading, which means that at compile time the entire code doesn't even need to exist yet! Global type inference is simply impossible in Scala. The best we could do is "whole-compilation-unit type inference", but that is undesirable, too: it would mean that whether or not you need type annotations depends on whether or not you compile your code in multiple units or just one.

Another important reason is that type annotations at module boundaries serve as a double-check, kind of like double-entry book keeping for types. Note that even in languages *with* global type inference like Haskell, it is strongly recommended to put type annotations on module boundaries and public interfaces.

A third reason is that global type inference can sometimes lead to confusing error messages, when instead of the type checker failing at a type annotation, the type inferencer happily chugs along inferring increasingly non-sensical types, until it *finally* gives up at a location far away from the *actual* error (which might just be a simple typo) with a type error that is only tangentially related to the original types at the error site. This can sometimes happen in Haskell, for example. The Scala designers value helpful error messages so much that they are willing to sacrifice language features unless they can figure out how to implement them with good error messages. (Note that even with Scala's very limited type inference, you can get such "helpful" messages as "expected `Foo` got `Product with Serializable`".)

However, what Scala's local type inference *can* do in this example, is to work in the other direction, and infer the parameter types of the anonymous function from the return type of `test`:

```
trait foo[F] {
  def test: F
}

class ah extends foo[(Int, Int) ⇒ Int] {
  def test = (i, j) ⇒ i + j
}

(new ah) test(2, 3) //=> 5
```

Comment: So Hindley-Milner would be able to infer the type of `foo` from `test`?

Comment: Scala has subtyping, which H-M doesn't support. (Unlike many functional languages, Scala's type system is pretty far from H-M.) But in a hypothetical language with global type inference and without subtyping and operator overloading, yes, it should be possible to infer all types with zero annotations: infer that `i` and `j` and the return type of the anonymous function are integers from the `+` operator (remember: no operator overloading), infer the type of `test` to be the function type of the anonymous function, infer `F` to be the return type of `test`. I think.

Comment: Yeah I agree for inferring for `test`, I was just wondering if it could use that information to also infer for `foo`. TBH I don't even know if standard class-like constructs are supported/allowed in H-M (without the subtyping part; just a simple type-parameterized class which has a method returning that type).

Comment: Classes and objects are typically modeled as records, which after all are just tuples with names, so yes, it is definitely possible. But note that Scala also deviates from other object-functional languages in this regard: many other object-functional languages identify functions with methods and objects with records. Scala identifies objects with functions and has methods be its own separate thing. Plus, like I said, subtyping and type inference really don't mix well, and subtyping is kinda a standard feature for typical class-like constructs.

Answer (score 1):

For you particular example, inferring type parameters based on inheritance can be ambiguous:

```
trait A
trait B extends A

trait Foo[T] {
    val x: T
}

trait Bar extends Foo[?] {
    val x: B
}
```

The type that could go in the `?` could be either `A` or `B`. This is a general example of where Scala will not infer types that could be ambiguous.

Now, you are correct to observe that there is a similarity between

```
class Foo[T](x: T)
```

and

```
trait Foo[T] { x: T }
```

I have seen work by some into possibly generalizing the similarity (but I can't seem to find it right now). That could, in theory, allow type inference of type parameters based on a member. But I don't know if it will ever get to that point.

Comment: Could that be in Dotty? I mean, Dotty doesn't have generics, they desugar into abstract type members. I.e. `trait Foo[T]; class IntFoo extends Foo[Int]` is actually `trait Foo { type T }; class IntFoo extends Foo { override type T = Int }` in Dotty.

Comment: By that argument, it also shouldn't infer return type of `def x = new B`: its type could also be `A` or `B` (or `Object`, or `Any`).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov You're right. The difference is that a trait can be subsequently extended, so the type parameter is both an upper and lower bound. That's why it's not safe to just infer the narrowest type that fits.

Comment: @Owen I'd say it's _more_ safe, but not completely. E.g. if your intention is actually to have `A`, but Scala infers `B`, you can't return `A` when overriding. One realistic case (as in, I've run into it personally) is when the intended return type is `Option[Something]` but the base implementation always returns `None` or `Some`.